# A question in plane geometry.

Tags: plane-geometry

$A,B$ are two fixed points in a plane. Given any third point $P$, can we always find a point $O$ such that either $\overline{OA}<\overline{OP}<\overline{OB}$ or $\overline{OB}<\overline{OP}<\overline{OA}$?

PS : I've asked many questions in this forum, but this is my first question in geometry, I'll be thrilled to learn an answer, as my plane geometry intuition is muddled and I am clueless. I hope the answer is surprisingly simple, elegant and enlightening.

Comment: I'm assuming $O$ and $P$ must also be in the plane?

Comment: @Nilknarf : Yes. Very much right. Its a plane geometry question. It may be simple but I am clueless.

Comment: I have added a strategy for finding $O$ if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the points are not colinear, then it is possible: just draw the perpendicular bisectors of the segments connecting each pair of points. This will divide space into six wedges; each wedge corresponds to one of the six possible orderings of the distance relationships.

[image]

Note that the red dot at the intersection is the center of the circle passing through the three points.

---

If the lines are colinear, however, this may not be possible as the perpendicular bisectors of the segments connecting each pair of points are parallel and divide space into only four regions. Thus, some of the six relations will not be possible.

[image]

Comment: What does $C$ correspond to? (in the question)

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: the question was essentially whether all order relations were possible. In that case, the letters used are irrelevant. However, to match the question, I have changed the letters in the diagrams.

Comment: Thanks rob. I knew the theme of our answer, just wanted to clear my own confusion.

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider the case in which $A$, $B$, and $P$ are all collinear so that $B$ bisects $\overline{AP}$. This is what it would look like:

[image]

As you can see, it is clear that no such $O$ can exist in this case.

If this is not the case, then $\triangle ABP$ exists. In this case, the strategy for finding $O$ would be to first find the circumcenter $C$ of the triangle so that $\overline{AC}=\overline{BC}=\overline{PC}$. Then rotate $C$ about $P$ some number of degrees such that the length $\overline{PC}$ stays the same, but $\overline{AC}$ increases and $\overline{BC}$ decreases, or vice versa. Then let $O$ be the image of $C$ and your conditions will be satisfied.

[image]

Comment: any points not on image $O$ will not satisfy the condition? You mean, $O$ is the set of all possible solutions?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Maybe this doesn't generate *all* possible points $O$, but it is a way to generate infinitely many such points.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the valuable answer. I am interested in all possible solutions. Is it just a curve, or its an area?

Comment: Well, it looks like you could turn it into an area as well... but the solution I gave just generates a curve of possible points. Glad to help! If I answered your question, don't forget to $\checkmark$! :D

Comment: The complement of the right bisector $r_{A,B}$ of the segment $AB$  is two half-planes $ p_A , p_B$ with $A\in p_A$ and $B\in p_B.$ Any point in $ p_A$ is closer to $A$ than to $B.$.....   The  complement of the right bisector $r_{P,B}$ of the segment $PB$ is two half-planes $q_P, q_B$ with $P\in q_P$ and $b\in q_B$. Any point in $q_P$ is closer to $P$ than to $A.$ .... If $P$ is not on the line thru $AB$ then $r_{A,B}, r_{P,B}$ are not parallel so the complement of $r_{A,B}\cup r_{P,B}$ is 4 non-empty regions. One of them  is $p_A\cap q_P,$ and any point $O$ in it will satisfy $AO<PO<BO.$

Answer (score 1):

<del>No. If $P$ is at the $AB$ line segment's bisector, then $A$ and $B$ are equidistant from $P$, hence no $O$ will make an $OP$ distance to be strictly between distances $OA$ and $OB$.</del>

<del>In any other case just draw circles through $A$ and through $B$, both centered at $P$ – each $O$ between the circles satisfies the requested condition.</del>

**EDIT**

I was wrong.

Comment: Suppose if $P$ is not on the bisector, is it then possible? Can you elaborate how to find $O$.